# MySql .Net connector is version specific

Tags: .net, mysql, amazon-ec2

when you install MySql's .Net connector it alters the machine.cfg of your .net environment and adds an entry in the db providers section which refers to the specific version of the connector you've installed.

This means whenever you update your local dev machines to a newer version of the connector you'll need to update your production server as well. Working with the AWS EC2 environment this means making a new AMI and updating your AutoScaler settings, etc. which incidentally seems to terminate all existing instances too!

Whilst I admit this is a workable process but it's far from ideal as this is likely to be an area where one might forget and to add to a botched update is a potentially lengthy downtime...

Does anyone know of a way to get around this so that you can start using a newer version of the connector without having to first make a new AMI?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to install the MySQL connector, you can just copy the DLL around.

I have no idea what AWS or EC2 is, but hopefully this is useful information. :)

Comment: When I first used the MySQL .NET connector, I used the installer.  Then I realized I could copy the DLL into my project without needing to install it on each machine, which was much more ideal.  It was *especially* ideal when I had to change the way the connector handled "zero dates" (e.g. '0000-00-00') so that it would play nicely with .NET.  All I had to do was change the source code of the connector, recompile and DLL, and deploy it locally in my project.

Comment: but don't you still need to ensure that a matching version of the connector is available on the server and the .Net framework on the server knows where to load the DB provider factories from? hence the need to run the installer on the server (which configures the machine.config file and add the necessary entries)?

Comment: oh, AWS = Amazon web services, and EC2 = its elastic cloud computing service, basically a way to get virtual machines based on usage, etc.

Comment: @theburningmonk: The client will talk to most server versions.  No server-side installation is required if you copy the DLL in the same directory as your application (which is what we do.)

Comment: thanks, we experimented with that and it works! we did have to make a change to the machine.config to register MySql as a db provider though, other than that, just had to copy to the dlls to the same directory as the app and it all works